# put in a personalized order with an array

Tags: php

I have a `.m3u` containing a playlist that would order according to my preferences. I suppose you could make it through an array, but I do not know how to set it up. Could you help me? Thank you.
This is the file that I

```
<a href='http://example.com/music/sound1.mp3>Michele</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/music1/sound1.mp3'>Antonio</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/music2/sound1.mp3'>Giuliano</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/music3/sound1.mp3'>Carlo</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/music3/sound1.mp3'>Pasquale</a><br/>
```

I wish I could give a personal order does not in alphabetical order:

```
<a href='http://example.com/music3/sound1.mp3'>Carlo</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/music/sound1.mp3>Michele</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/music3/sound1.mp3'>Pasquale</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/music1/sound1.mp3'>Antonio</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/music2/sound1.mp3'>Giuliano</a><br/>
```

Comment: I'm looking at the network an example, but I only find examples by alphabetical order

Comment: In what order you want them ?

Comment: From the first to the second list I made an example, I would like with my personal order of watching the url name, for example,

Comment: @George: You didn't answer the question. What are you using to order the list?

Comment: How would you like the `php` to know the "personal" order ?

Comment: The list that I would like to order is a list of TV channels for streaming, when unloading the file that contains the url are in random order, while I would like to rewrite with php file in an order with the channel name, which is why I only know that I should put an array but do not know how to do, I'm just a beginner in programming php